# Docker compose postgresql service - can't create user and database during build?

Tags: postgresql, docker, docker-compose, psql

I have wasted an entire day on this, and to say I'm not impressed by the unnecessary complexity of what should be a simple task - would be a gross understatement.

Ok, having got that off my chest, I am building a django application using docker-machine, docker-compose, postgresql and redis - by following [this tutorial](https://realpython.com/blog/python/django-development-with-docker-compose-and-machine/).

I have managed to get the basic tutorial to work - but it does not suit my needs, as I need to create a user and a database for my application - as opposed to using 'postgres' for both.

I have used the answer from @dnephin to a [similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33309121/using-docker-compose-to-create-tables-in-postgresql-database), and modified my code as follows:

I created a new Dockerfile in a new directory `./database/`:

```
FROM postgres:9.6
COPY . /fixtures
WORKDIR /fixtures
RUN /fixtures/setup.sh
```

`./database/setup.sh` contents:

```
#!/bin/bash
set -e

pg_createcluster 9.6 main --start
/etc/init.d/postgresql start
su - postgres # makes no effing difference ...
psql -f create_fixtures.sql    
/etc/init.d/postgresql stop
```

`./database/create_fixtures.sql` contents:

```
CREATE DATABASE mydatabase WITH ENCODING 'UTF8';
CREATE USER webuser ENCRYPTED PASSWORD 'deadbeefsnaf0' NOSUPERUSER NOCREATEDB NOCREATEROLE;
GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON mydatabase TO webuser;
```

and finally my postgres service in the docker_compose.yml is modified to use build:

```
postgres:
    build: ./database/
    ...
```

When I run `docker-compose build`, the build goes through the motions and then *barfs* at where I'm importing the SQL fixtures file via **psql**:

```
frothing@themouth:~/path/to/directory$ docker-compose build
redis uses an image, skipping
Building postgres
Step 1/4 : FROM postgres:9.6
 ---> ff0943ecbb3c
Step 2/4 : COPY . /fixtures
 ---> fae19dc88da8
Removing intermediate container 84b860aee55c
Step 3/4 : WORKDIR /fixtures
 ---> aa88438dc69f
Removing intermediate container b801ddc3b374
Step 4/4 : RUN /fixtures/setup.sh
 ---> Running in ca3e89ec2460
Creating new cluster 9.6/main ...
  config /etc/postgresql/9.6/main
  data   /var/lib/postgresql/9.6/main
  locale en_US.utf8
  socket /var/run/postgresql
  port   5432
Starting PostgreSQL 9.6 database server: main.
psql: FATAL:  role "root" does not exist
ERROR: Service 'postgres' failed to build: The command '/bin/sh -c /fixtures/setup.sh' returned a non-zero code: 2
```

I tried to solve this using the [useless documentation on docker for postgresql service](https://docs.docker.com/engine/examples/postgresql_service/) - but got no where.

**How can I solve this?**

Comment: I think you should use the "postgres" user not root to start your script. You can specify a user with the `USER` keyword.

Comment: @papey when I specify `USER postgres` in my ./database/DockerFile (just before importing the SQL statements file). I get the following error output when I run `docker-compose build`:  install: cannot change owner and permissions of ‘/etc/postgresql/9.6’: No such file or directory
install: cannot create directory ‘/etc/postgresql/9.6’: Permission denied
Error: could not create configuration directory; you might need to run this program with root privileges

Comment: I think there is multiple problems here : 1) there is no init inside a standard docker container, using /etc/init.d will probably fail. 2) You're psql command is excuted by root and default postgres config avoid connexion by root user.

Comment: @papey I appreciate you're trying to help. But simply guessing at what the problem might be is **not helping**. Regarding your suggestions: 1). If you look at the console output I posted, there is no problem in starting the postgres service via init.d  2). The problem does not go away, if I use the `USER` directive to change user from root to postgresql.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Volumes are not available at build time. You can create `/var/lib/postgresql/data` in your script but it will be overwritten by `VOLUME /var/lib/postgresql/data` from `postgres:9.6` image.

In your case: just use the following docker file:

```
FROM postgres:9.6
COPY ./create_fixtures.sql /docker-entrypoint-initdb.d/create_fixtures.sql
```

They get automatically executed once the container starts. Here is an example:

```
$ docker run -d --name mydb -p 33306:3306 yourtag
$ docker exec -ti mydb psql -U postgres
postgres=# \l
                                 List of databases
    Name    |  Owner   | Encoding |  Collate   |   Ctype    |   Access privileges   
------------+----------+----------+------------+------------+-----------------------
 mydatabase | postgres | UTF8     | en_US.utf8 | en_US.utf8 | =Tc/postgres         +
            |          |          |            |            | postgres=CTc/postgres+
            |          |          |            |            | webuser=CTc/postgres
 postgres   | postgres | UTF8     | en_US.utf8 | en_US.utf8 | 
 template0  | postgres | UTF8     | en_US.utf8 | en_US.utf8 | =c/postgres          +
            |          |          |            |            | postgres=CTc/postgres
 template1  | postgres | UTF8     | en_US.utf8 | en_US.utf8 | =c/postgres          +
            |          |          |            |            | postgres=CTc/postgres
(4 rows)
```

---

Outdated answer:

Your script should work *on a container* except in the fixture you have to execute psql like this:

```
su postgres -c "psql -f create_fixtures.sql"
```

`su --login postgres` does not work because postgres can't open a bash or shell. You can try around with `docker run --rm -ti postgres:9.6 bash`.

Sorry I have to tell you there is one more error in your sql script: `GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON DATABASE mydatabase TO webuser` - the keyword `DATABASE` is necessary here.

Here is a complete log how I tested and can confirm this works:

```
docker run --rm -ti postgres:9.6 bash
root@be03ab1eb704:/# cat > test.sql <<EOF
> CREATE DATABASE mydatabase WITH ENCODING 'UTF8';
> CREATE USER webuser ENCRYPTED PASSWORD 'asdf123' NOSUPERUSER NOCREATEDB NOCREATEROLE;
> GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON DATABASE mydatabase TO webuser;
> EOF
root@be03ab1eb704:/# pg_createcluster 9.6 main --start
Creating new PostgreSQL cluster 9.6/main ...                                                                                                  
/usr/lib/postgresql/9.6/bin/initdb -D /var/lib/postgresql/9.6/main --auth-local peer --auth-host md5                                          
The files belonging to this database system will be owned by user "postgres".                                                                 
This user must also own the server process.                                                                                                   

The database cluster will be initialized with locale "en_US.utf8".                                                                            
The default database encoding has accordingly been set to "UTF8".                                                                             
The default text search configuration will be set to "english".                                                                               

Data page checksums are disabled.                                                                                                             

fixing permissions on existing directory /var/lib/postgresql/9.6/main ... ok                                                                  
creating subdirectories ... ok                                                                                                                
selecting default max_connections ... 100                                                                                                     
selecting default shared_buffers ... 128MB                                                                                                    
selecting dynamic shared memory implementation ... posix                                                                                      
creating configuration files ... ok                                                                                                           
running bootstrap script ... ok                                                                                                               
performing post-bootstrap initialization ... ok                                                                                               
syncing data to disk ... ok                                                                                                                   

Success. You can now start the database server using:                                                                                         

    /usr/lib/postgresql/9.6/bin/pg_ctl -D /var/lib/postgresql/9.6/main -l logfile start                                                       

Ver Cluster Port Status Owner    Data directory               Log file                                                                        
9.6 main    5432 online postgres /var/lib/postgresql/9.6/main /var/log/postgresql/postgresql-9.6-main.log                                     
root@be03ab1eb704:/# /etc/init.d/postgresql start
[ ok ] Starting PostgreSQL 9.6 database server: main.                                                                                         
root@be03ab1eb704:/# su postgres -c "psql -f test.sql"
CREATE DATABASE                                                                                                                               
CREATE ROLE
GRANT
root@be03ab1eb704:/# /etc/init.d/postgresql stop
[ ok ] Stopping PostgreSQL 9.6 database server: main.
root@be03ab1eb704:/# exit
exit
```

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion, but I get the following error, when I follow your instructions: `install: cannot change owner and permissions of ‘/etc/postgresql/9.6’: No such file or directory
install: cannot create directory ‘/etc/postgresql/9.6’: Permission denied
Error: could not create configuration directory; you might need to run this program with root privileges
ERROR: Service 'postgres' failed to build: The command '/bin/sh -c /fixtures/setup.sh' returned a non-zero code: 1`

Comment: you still have `pg_createcluster 9.6 main --start` and `/etc/init.d/postgresql start` in your script, right?  it works on my machine.. I will update the answer - wait a minute

Comment: sorry - maybe I understand the problem now. I think the volume from postgres 9.6 is just not available at build time. volumes are not available at build time at all - they get bound when you start the container. you will have to execute this script in entrypoint.sh. will update the answer

Comment: Thanks for the updated answer - at least, that's got rid of the errors I was getting before. **However**, I want to log into the database and **MAKE SURE** that the objects (specified in my create_fixtures.sql have been created). When I run `docker-compose up -d`, I get the names of the containers (for this purpose, we're only interested in the postgres container): **Creating container mywebapp_postgres_1**. I then try to login, using the command `docker run --rm -ti mywebapp_postgres_1 bash`, and I get the error: `Unable to find image 'mywebapp_postgres_1:latest' locally` ???

Comment: Just use: `docker-compose exec postgres psql -U webuser mydatabase`

Comment: Thanks very much for your help. I will give you +1 for your last statement that helped me log into the database - and award the bonus to you too. I have **finally** been able to get this to work. Any good links on using docker-compose? I find the docker site documentation too terse, and with not enough useful examples/scenarios.

Comment: I'm just fine with google, github, stackoverflow and docker/docker-compose docs: https://docs.docker.com/compose/reference/overview/

Answer (score 1):

The official postgresql docker image automatically imports scripts at the first start of a container. So if you mount your directory with your init sql script to container path '/docker-entrypoint-initdb.d/' it should be run.

For example if you have your import script myImport.sql and it's on your host in a directory /opt/import, you can mount the import directory on container start to your postgres image to /docker-entrypoint-initdb.d and the sql file will be executed after initial database setup.

```
docker run -p $toHostParam:5432 -e POSTGRES_PASSWORD="$dbPwd" \
-e POSTGRES_USER="$dbUser" \
-e POSTGRES_DB="$dbName" \
-e PGDATA=/opt/pgdata \
-v ${dataDir}:/opt/pgdata \
# look here
# mount of local import dir
-v /opt/import:/docker-entrypoint-initdb.d \
 postgres:9.6
```

Take a look at the postgesql image start script here (from line 126):
https://github.com/docker-library/postgres/blob/master/9.6/docker-entrypoint.sh

If you want a specific db user or database you can also customize your postgresql container with environment variables.

Take a look at the 'Environment Variables' section here: https://hub.docker.com/_/postgres/

Comment: I don't understand this statement: **So if you mount your directory with your init sql script to container path '/docker-entrypoint-initdb.d/' it should be run** - could you clarify? - _**preferably, with an example?**_ at the moment, I am copying my init files to the entry point directory `COPY init.sql /docker-entrypoint-initdb.d/10-init.sql` yet after I build the image, and log into the database, none of the database objects I specified in my init files have been created.

Comment: @HomunculusReticulli I modified my post

Answer (score 0):

Try with this setup.sh

```
#!/bin/bash
set -e

pg_createcluster 9.6 main --start
su postgres sh -c "/etc/init.d/postgresql start && psql -f create_fixtures.sql && /etc/init.d/postgresql stop"
```

Comment: This is the console output when I try the modifications you suggested: `install: cannot change owner and permissions of ‘/etc/postgresql/9.6’: No such file or directory
install: cannot create directory ‘/etc/postgresql/9.6’: Permission denied
Error: could not create configuration directory; you might need to run this program with root privileges
ERROR: Service 'postgres' failed to build: The command '/bin/sh -c /fixtures/setup.sh' returned a non-zero code: 1`

Answer (score 0):

Try a explicit user when running psql:

```
psql -U postgres -f create_fixtures.sql
```

Comment: did you try what you recommended - or did you just "guess"?. This is the result when I try what you recommended: `install: cannot change owner and permissions of ‘/etc/postgresql/9.6’: No such file or directory
install: cannot create directory ‘/etc/postgresql/9.6’: Permission denied
Error: could not create configuration directory; you might need to run this program with root privileges
ERROR: Service 'postgres' failed to build: The command '/bin/sh -c /fixtures/setup.sh' returned a non-zero code: 1`

Comment: The error your reported happens because `-U role` was omitted from psql command, in this case psql try to connect with OS user. You can edit `./database/setup.sh` adding what I said, but remember that you need ensure proper permissions on `./database/create_fixtures.sql` for that user.

Comment: No, I told you I entered the command, **exactly** as you specified - i.e. by explicitly specifying the user, in the bash script.